# the network dropped on ubuntu 12.04 server but came back

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, log-files

I have a ubuntu server, type 12.04 that serves as a mysql box and intranet server. Without notice it dropped all packets (www, ping and mysql). What logs should i check - the messages log is not in the usual /var/log location, and how can I read the "date" out of what the dmesg log states?

no other servers on the same switch was down - and it was down for about 3-5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The messages log is not in the usual /var/log location**

The `messages` log file is called `/var/log/syslog` in Ubuntu. To see which system messages are included in `syslog` see `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. On my Ubuntu 12.04 it looks like this:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
```

which logs everything.

(For the curious, the dash mark (-) that precedes the file path disables running sync() to flush the file system buffers after writing out each line.)

**How can I read the "date" out of what the dmesg log states?**

`/var/log/kern.log` provides timestamps to `dmesg`'s output.

**What logs should I check?**

You are probably interested in kernel messages like these:

```
Mar 13 08:33:22 ubuntu kernel: [213187.021594] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Mar 13 08:33:24 ubuntu kernel: [213188.913440] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Mar 13 08:33:46 ubuntu kernel: [213199.013501] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

You can find them in both `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. The former is convenient to quickly locate kernel messages, the latter is convenient to provide context for those messages, that is, to see which other activities were logged when they were generated.